# Shinyapps.io application deployment failure. How to debug ambiguous error log?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm trying to deploy a shiny app that works locally to my shinyapps.io account. When I try to deploy the app, I get the following error message. I can confirm that I have no references to local working directories. I'm not really sure what this error log is telling me though. How should I interpret it? I have a hunch the problem results from the app's use of the RCurl library (I fixed a previous error resulting from this library), but I can't be sure.

[image]

Comment: Looks like there may be an error in line 1. You did not include the code for line 1, or any of the lines, so it's kinda hard to tell.

Comment: I knew I'd get yelled at for not including the code, but unfortunately I can't. However, I can say with confidence that the problem is not on line one (which is: library(shinydashboard). That's why I'm asking... I don't understand how to read this error log and then find the bugs in my code. This error log is gibberish to me since it doesn't look like a typical R console error log.

Comment: Oh, that "line 1" error may be a result of reading in a dataset. Header row has 4 elements, line 1 does not.